# I want to log an action everytime a user clicks (highlights) an input field to enter a value into it. What can I do to achieve such functionality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I am using React if that helps.

I'm working on some user actions analytics for my website which has a form. I'm adding a logger on some user actions. One of them being I want to log every time the user clicks on the input field to enter some value into it. How can I achieve this functionality?

I was thinking of `onClick` but I don't think that would be the best way to go about it cause that wouldn't serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

<input **onClick**={logCount}>

More info about events:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you're claiming an onclick event wouldn't be the right approach.

You can add an ID to the input tag and access it through a JavaScript file, adding an onclick event to it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="test">
        <script>
            document.getElementById('test').onclick = function() {
                console.log('An input field with the id "test" has been clicked.')
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```